# Writing a program that represents an 8×8 grid?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

This is from a textbook:

"Write a program that creates a string that represents an 8×8 grid, using newline characters to separate lines. At each position of the grid there is either a space or a "#" character. The characters should form a chessboard."

The chessboard looks like this:

```
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # #
```

This is my code:

```
const lineOne = ' # # # # '

const lineTwo = '# # # #'

const chessboard = function() {
  console.log(lineOne)
  console.log(lineTwo)
  console.log(lineOne)
  console.log(lineTwo)
  console.log(lineOne)
  console.log(lineTwo)
  console.log(lineOne)
  console.log(lineTwo)
}

console.log(chessboard())
```

While this does output the chessboard, I can tell that this is very inefficient. What is a better way of writing this?

Also the textbook writes, once I have finished writing the program that 
outputs the chessboard that I should set a binding: size = 8 and change the program so that it works for any size, outputting a grid of the given width and height.

How does one do this? I am told we need a loop inside a loop, but I can't figure it out?

Bear in mind that I am a novice who is learning, so the more you explain the better.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I want to thank ALL of your for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your book says, we can do this with a couple of `for` loops.  We'll have one loop for the line (the `y` coordinate), and the column (the `x` coordinate).

A for loop is usually used to to execute something a certain number of times.  (Technically, it's until a condition is met.)  Here's an example:

```
for (let y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
  // Do something
}
```

In this example, we're initializing the `y` variable with the value `0`.  As long as `y` is less than `8`, we're going to keep running this loop.  Also, every loop, we're going to add `1` to the value of `y`.  (That's what the `++` operator does.)

Now, our "do something" can have another loop inside of it.  Putting this together, here's the code you need:

```
const gridSize = 8;

for (let y = 0; y<gridSize; y++) {
  let line = '';
  for (let x=0; x<gridSize; x++) {
    line += ((x+y)%2) ? ' ' : '#';
  }
  console.log(line);
}
```

The outer loop is for lines, and the inner loop is for columns.  Now, you'll see this particular line in the inner loop:

```
line += ((x+y)%2) ? ' ' : '#';
```

Starting with `line +=`...

What this means is that we're going to take the `line` variable and concatenate some data to it.  That is, since it's a string, the `+=` operator takes the existing text data and puts more text on the end of it, re-assigning it back to the `line` variable.

Now, `(x+y) % 2`...

First, the modulus operator `%`.  `0 % 2` is `0`, `1 % 2` is `1`, `2 % 2` is `0`, `3 % 2` is `1`, and so on.  Basically, divide, and whatever the remainder is is what you get.  In this case, we add the row `x` and the column `y` so that we'll alternate odd/even values for every row.  The result of this will either be `1` or `0`.

`((x+y)%2) ? ' ' : '#'`...

This is called a ternary.  `something ? 'truthy' : 'falsy'` means that if `something` is true (or truthy, like `1`), then return `'truthy'`.  If not, return `'falsy'`.  In our case, if the row plus column are odd, return an empty space (which gets concatenated to the line).  Otherwise if it's even, return a `#` (which also gets concatenated to the line).

After each inner loop, output the line, and start over.

Answer (score 1):

I think for the beginner this is the most simplest way.

Here are the steps to do this:

1. Iterate the `2 loops` with `size of chessboard`.Outer loop will represent to `line` while inner is for `column`.
   //Here loop iterate **(from 0 to < size)** means 0 to 7.
2. Inside inner loop decide that `outer loop` index is  `even` or `odd` based on modules.It will decide the start column of line will be `space` or `block(#)`.
3. Inside **`this if and else`** just find out inner loop index is  `even` or `odd` and append  column **( `space` or `block(#)`)** on basis of it.

```js
var size = 8;
var block = '#';
var space = ' ';

function chessBoard(ChessSize){
  for (var i = 0; i < ChessSize; i++) {
  var drawLine = '';
  for (var y = 0; y < ChessSize; y++){
    if (i%2) {
        if (y%2) {
            drawLine = drawLine + space;
        } else {
            drawLine = drawLine + block;
        }
    } else {
        if (y%2) {
            drawLine = drawLine + block;
        } else {
            drawLine = drawLine + space;
        }
    }
  }
  console.log(drawLine);
}
}
chessBoard(size);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a chessboard, call each cell `A[i, j]`. `i` is row index, `j` is the column index.

- All cells whose `i + j` is even are black.
- All cells whose `i + j` is odd are white.

```js
var numberColumns = 8;

for (var i = 0; i < numberColumns; i++) {
  var line  = ""
  for (var j = 0; j < numberColumns; j++) {
     line += ((i + j) % 2 ? "#" : " ");
  }
  // print the new line
  console.log(line + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use 2 loops
2. Detect odd and even rows.
3. Write to a buffer.

```js
function createGrid(size) {
  var s = ''
  for (var row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    var oddRow = row % 2 == 0
    if (oddRow) {
      s += ' '
    }
    for (var col = 0; col < size; col++) {
      s += ' #';
    }
    s += '\n'
  }
  return s
}

console.log(createGrid(8))
console.log()
console.log(createGrid(16))
```

Answer (score -1):

Looping makes your code shorter than it is.

Instead of printing the `# # # #`, 8 times you can write it in a loop to let the program print it 8 times by just writing it 1 time.

The `if` condition inside the loop will just make the printing alternate so it will make it look like a chess board.

The loop starts at 1 and ends at 8 it is represented by the variable `i`. In that case we can distinguish alternate as odd and even numbers.

The `if` condition will print `lineTwo` if the `i` variable is an even number and will print `lineOne` if the `i` variable is an odd number.

The loop makes it more dynamic since you will just change the end of the loop represented by the variable `size` currently at `8` on any number you want.

```js
const lineOne = ' # # # # '

const lineTwo = '# # # #'

const size = 8

const chessboard = function() {
  for ( let i = 1; i <= size; i++ ) {
    if ( i % 2 === 0 ) {
      console.log(lineTwo)
    }
    else {
      console.log(lineOne)
    }
  }
}

console.log(chessboard())
```

**UPDATED:**

```js
const chessboard = (size) => {
  for ( let i = 1; i <= size; i++ ) {
    var row = ''
    for ( let j = 1; j <= size; j++ ) {
      i % 2 === 0 ? j % 2 === 0 ? row += '#' : row += ' ' : j % 2 === 0 ? row += ' ' : row += '#'
    }
    console.log(row + "\n")
  }
}

console.log(chessboard(8)) //pass the size of the chessboard here
```

I remade the chessboard function to accept a variable which holds the size of the chessboard.

I created another loop inside a loop. The loop above is the same just like I did in the first example. But in the second loop, it prints `# # # #` in an alternate pattern. Instead of writing the string as a fixed string we made it more dynamic.

Comment: You should explain what this is actually doing rather than blindly posting the code.  This person needs help understanding how loops work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but now your code has a fixed line size.